# Can I load a tensorflow model after modifying the graph?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to modify the graph (add ops with no trainable variables) of existing code using tensorflow and load a pretrained model for fine-tuning. While simply loading the model after modifying gives no error, I am confused why tensorflow could still matching the variable with the data. What if I add some ops with trainable variables or I modify the name of the original variables?

#### Code

The code I am working on is too long so I put dummy code here.

Originally

```
# build graph
w = tf.Variable(..., name='weight')
b = tf.Variable(..., name='bias')
x = tf.placeholder(..., name='input')
y = W * x + b
label = tf.placeholder(..., name='label')
loss = (y-label) * (y-label)

# normal training and saving
...
```

And I modified the program and load the model

```
# build graph
w = tf.Variable(..., name='weight')
b = tf.Variable(..., name='bias')
x = tf.placeholder(..., name='input')
y = W * x + b
label = tf.placeholder(..., name='label')
label = label * 0.5                           # add an op
loss = (y-label) * (y-label)

# load model
saver.restore(sess, 'path/to/model')
```

It works well. If I change the name of the variable or add new variables

```
# build graph
w = tf.Variable(..., name='weight_2')         # changed name
b = tf.Variable(..., name='bias')
scalar = tf.Variable(..., name='scalar')      # add variable
x = tf.placeholder(..., name='input')
y = scalar * W * x + b
label = tf.placeholder(..., name='label')
label = label * 0.5                           # add an op
loss = (y-label) * (y-label)

# load model
saver.restore(sess, 'path/to/model')
```

Will it still work?

Comment: Could you add some code so it is easier to help you?

Comment: @zhangjy Did you figure out what was happening? I have trained my model. However I want to change the graph (add a placeholder, take one out and add a few operations), restore from a checkpoint and then save the model using savedModel builder for serving. I am wondering if this will affect the model somehow or if this is even possible.